# Vertical Alignment & Horizontal Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout like this, that is both horizontally and vertically centered.

[image]

I have figured out a way to do this with jQuery, but there seems to be a slight jerk as the page renders.  I was hoping to do this layout with pure css, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  Here is the fiddle for this layout.  Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/rodmjay/LnRq6/

Comment: It should help to specify the image dimensions in the `<img>` tag, so the browser knows how to render them before they've begun downloading.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of vertical align and display in your CSS will do the trick:

```
#container .item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is OK in most browsers *except* IE7 and below.  IE8 is fine.  Go figure.

Comment: how would you do a float with this.  I had the items wrapping lines.... see exmaple... http://jsfiddle.net/LnRq6/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think that its impossible to align vertically this with pure css and without tables. You need that all elements have the same height for align them vertically.

UPDATE 2016: You can use display flex, its amazing for this