# Error with aligning some text

Tags: html, css

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brJEc/)

I am trying to get the text "Message" aligned to the top so it is right next to where the message box starts instead of it being at the bottom of the box, I have tried multiple methods and have tried using tables however the table does not give me the look that I am wanting. What would be the best way to make this work?

**Codes I have tried:**

```
vertical-align:text-top;
```

and

```
text-align: top;
```

None of the above samples work to give me the output I need.

Comment: omg, duplicate of SO MANY OTHERS, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759574/vertical-alignment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127676/vertical-alignment-horizontal-alignment-issue. Please search before asking this question for the millionth time.

Comment: @Colleen - There are more polite, and official ways of saying what you just said.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
vertical-align: top;
```

That said, I know tables aren't fashionable, but it does look like tabular layout to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.contacttitle {
width: 100px;
font-size: 18px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: top;
}
```

See the results here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EBGGg/